# Property seems to be changing between method calls, but no code is supposed to be changing it

Tags: c#, list, count, command-query-separation

I have an `Octet` class that is suppose to "package" eight samples and then send them forward. It has methods to add a new sample, check if it is already full, and to extract a `Frame` datastructure built from the eight values from the `Octet`.

The `Octet` class throws two kinds of exceptions: "cannot extract because not yet full" and "cannot add sample because already full". For that, the client code should check if full before calling `Add`, and extract as soon as is full, as well as to reset it (quite a lame class contract, to be honest).

The problem is: I am getting the two kinds of errors, even though the client class - the only one using `Octet` - seems to be performing the checks correctly before the operations that throw, but even though the error conditions are being hit. To make matters worse, when I check the values when debugger breaks, they are correct, that is, the exceptions should not be throwing!

```
public class Client
{
    private Octet _octet = new Octet();

    void ProcessNewSamples(IEnumerable<int> newSamples)
    {
        foreach (int sample in newSamples)
        {
            if (!_octet.IsFull)
            {
                _octet.Add(sample);
            }

            if (_octet.IsFull)
            {
                var frame = _octet.ExtractFrame();
                this.SendElsewhere(frame);
                _octet.Reset();
            }

        }
    }
}


public class Octet
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 8;
    int[] _samples = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int _index = 0;

    public bool IsFull { get { return _index >= 8; } }

    public void Add(int sample)
    {
        if (IsFull)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        else
            _samples[_index++] = sample;
    }

    public Frame<int> ExtractFrame()
    {
        if (!IsFull)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        else
            return new Frame<int>(_samples);

    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _samples = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
        _index = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `ProcessNewSamples` called from multiple threads? If so, you should lock you access to the octet in the function.

Comment: @heinzbeinz Ok, I have found that the task where the code is running is called more than one time inadvertently. Well, this sure is a defect in the client code, and I'm gonna fix it. But regarding the `lock` strategy, could you post it as an answer? I'm not sure the best place to put the lock. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you should place a lock if your function is accessed in parallel.

If `SendElsewhere` is fast, I simply would place the lock around the function:

```
void ProcessNewSamples(IEnumerable<int> newSamples)
{
    lock (this)
    {
        foreach (int sample in newSamples)
        {
            if (!_octet.IsFull)
            {
                _octet.Add(sample);
            }

            if (_octet.IsFull)
            {
                var frame = _octet.ExtractFrame();
                this.SendElsewhere(frame);
                _octet.Reset();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise I would collect all frames and send them afterwards:

```
void ProcessNewSamples(IEnumerable<int> newSamples)
{
    var frames = new List<Frame>();

    lock (this)
    {
        foreach (int sample in newSamples)
        {
            if (!_octet.IsFull)
            {
                _octet.Add(sample);
            }

            if (_octet.IsFull)
            {
                var frame = _octet.ExtractFrame();
                frames.Add(frame);
                _octet.Reset();
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (var frame in frames)
    {
        this.SendElsewhere(frame)
    }
}
```